# Powershell Get-WinEvent Xpath Query not valid

Tags: powershell, xpath, get-winevent

I would know what's wrong in my query ?

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Application' -FilterXPath "/Event/System/Provider[@Name = 'My App']"
```

Each time I get the exception below:

```
*Get-WinEvent : La requête spécifiée n’est pas valide
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Application' -FilterXPath "/Event/System/Provider[@Name = ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand*
```

Below the XML code of an event

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
    <Provider Name="My App" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">24</EventID> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-12T08:43:57.000000000Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>37160382</EventRecordID> 
    <Channel>Application</Channel> 
    <Computer>Apps.Server</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
    <Data>Some additional data</Data>
```

Many thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: I don't know whether the XPath engine you are using is conformant with the spec, but if it is, then unqualified names like `Event` and `System` will only match elements that are in no namespace: but all the elements in your XML are in namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/win....`. So it shouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Remove '/' before Event

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Application' -FilterXPath "Event/System/Provider[@Name = 'My App']"

Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Application' -FilterXPath "Event/EventData/Data = '6.3.9600.18376'"
```

Comment: But right know if I want to look up a substring in a string, I get an exception too: -FilterXPath "Event/EventData/Data[contains(text(),'Exception')]"

Comment: `code`Get-WinEvent -LogName "Application" -FilterXPath "Event/EventData/Data[contains(text(),'Exception')]"

Comment: <Data>contains(text(),'Exception')</Data>..........
Does data contains "contains(text(),'Exception'"

Comment: <data> doesn't contain the string "contains(text(),'Exception')" but contains a string with word "Exception". That's I want to get.<br />To get the value of <data> I use the `code`Event/EventData/Data[text()]